# Visual Studio Code has imported all folders associated with primary user of laptop,

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently made VScode my primary IDE and it has since imported ALL of the folders associated with the primary user of my laptop. So folders associated with Dropbox, Applications, Creative Cloud, etc..etc.. are now showing up in the Explorer, under my name.

How do I remove these folders so that I can choose which folders I would like to open for my coding projects?

I can't find answers to this anywhere.

I've included a screenshot so that you can see what I am talking about.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s03D.png)

Comment: You opened `~`. Close it

Answer (score 0):

vs code can be opened from a directory. it show all directory and file in pwd.
to open vs code in a directory you can execute `code <path/to/where/you/want>` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you are concerned that VSCode is showing all the folders you have when you open it up.

Let me clarify things for you:

1. Vscode is not an IDE, it's an advanced text editor.
2. Vscode does not import any files anywhere. It just works as a file browser;
   it lists the files and folders of the folder that was opened in.

In your case, I think when you open up VScode, it's showing you the content of the /home directory (you are using linux or mac). If you want to open a specific folder, go to "Files" and then "Open Folder" and select the folder you want to open.